pandas explode list values row wise
I have a Dataframe like this
data = [[1, [10, 11]], [1, [15, 16]], [2, [20, 24]], [2, [22, 23]]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'val']) 

   id   val
0   1   [10, 11]
1   2   [15, 16]

Here length of each list in val is same.
I want to explode val row wise. I could not fine a direct way of doing it .
So as work around I used
df.explode('val')

Now I want to use df.pivot but before that I want to add column names for each id.
Something like this
    id  val col_name
0   1   10  col_1
0   1   11  col_2
1   2   15  col_1
1   2   16  col_2

How can I add col_name using groupby??
This will help me pivot the dataframe.
Also is there any direct way of explode row wise which looks like
id   col_1  col_2       
1   10      11
2   15      16


chk the code that creates the input dataframe.

Code
out = pd.DataFrame(df['val'].tolist(), index=df['id'], columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])

out
    col_1   col_2
id      
1   10      11
2   15      16


if have many columns, use following code:
out = (pd.DataFrame(df['val'].tolist(), index=df['id'])
         .rename(lambda x: f'col_{x + 1}', axis=1)
)

same result

is there any way to avoid tolist() as for big data it may not be efficient

@BharatSharma Is it a check with big data? Or is it just a feeling? use tolist because it's more efficient than other methods.
